# How to get first word of strings in columns and get the levels of it?

Tags: r, dataframe, levels

I have a dataframe  `df` like:

```
      v1
1    "john lins"  
2    "carl sagan"  
3    "mary lee"
4    "sara jones"
5    "john Santos"
6    "mary jones"
```

I needed to get the first names, so I did it using `gsub()` like:

```
df[,2] <- gsub("(\\w+).*", "\\1", df[,1])
```

Then I got:

```
      v1              v2
1    "john lins"     "john"  
2    "carl sagan"    "carl"  
3    "mary lee"      "mary"
4    "sara jones"    "sara"
5    "john Santos"   "john"
6    "mary jones"    "mary"
```

But now I need to get the levels of `df$v2`.

I thought that with `levels(df$v2)` I would get something like:

```
[1]  "john"   "carl"    "mary"   "sara"
```

But instead, it returns `NULL` 
Is there someway to get levels of it?

Answer (score 0):

There are no levels, since it is still just a vector of strings. Convert it to a factor, and you should get levels. (`levels(factor(df$v2))`)

Comment: `levels(factor(df$v2))` returns `character(0)`

Comment: I was working off the point where we wrote "Then I got:". That data frame can be reproduced with: `df  <- data.frame(v1 = c('john lins', 'carl sagan', 'mary lee', 'sara jones', 'john santos', 'mary jones'), v2 = c('john', 'carl', 'mary', 'sara', 'john', 'mary'), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`, from which `level(factor(df$v2))` returns `"carl" "john" "mary" "sara"`

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues here.

1. There is no column `v2` (lower case `v`) in `df`. So, `levels(df$v2)` is trying to access a non existing column.
2. But even with the correct column name `V2` (capital `V`) `levels(df$V2)` will fail because `V2` is not a factor.

This is revealed by a call to

```
str(df)
```

> ```
> 'data.frame': 6 obs. of  2 variables:
>  $ v1: Factor w/ 6 levels "carl sagan","john lins",..: 2 1 5 6 3 4
>  $ V2: chr  "john" "carl" "mary" "sara" ...
> ```

If you are after the unique names in `V2` you may simply call

```
unique(df$V2)
```

> ```
> [1] "john" "carl" "mary" "sara"
> ```

to get the unique "levels".

This is equivalent to

```
levels(factor(df$V2))
```

> ```
> [1] "carl" "john" "mary" "sara"
> ```

[(see rmuraglia's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45250548/3817004) but note that `factor()` sorts the levels alphabetically while `unique()` keeps the unique values in the order of appearance.

#### Data

```
df <- data.frame(v1 = c("john lins",   
                        "carl sagan",   
                        "mary lee",
                        "sara jones",
                        "john Santos",
                        "mary jones"))
df[, 2] <- gsub("(\\w+).*", "\\1", df[, 1])
```